# Is Average Precision for ranking problems computed the same way as in classification?

Tags: classification, ranking

For classification, we calculate Average Precision (AP) as area under the PR curve. But for ranking problems, we calculate it via the relevance of the items at certain ranked positions. Are these 2 equivalent?